# Magento Product Collection Filter by Custom Multiple Select Attribute

Tags: php, magento

I have an almost complete solution for showing Magento products selectively by region.

The regions are:
UK
Europe
Americas
Middle East
Rest of World

All customers have been assigned a region, which I have made available via the variable $customerRegion.

All my Magento Products have a custom attribute 'product_region', which has region options available for multiple selection.

list.phtml should only present products that match the customer's region. I have a partially working solution:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_region',
        array('eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
            ->getAttribute('product_region')
            ->getSource()
            ->getOptionId($customerRegion)
        )
    )
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

If the customer's region is UK, and the product's region is UK, the filter works as expected.
If the customer's region is UK, and the product's region is UK AND Europe, the filter does not work as expected (no results are given).

How can I adjust the filter to get the desired behaviour?

I have tried using 'in' and 'like' instead of 'eq' but have not been successful.

Thank you.

P.S. An easier way to view the same problem is to look at the following code:

```
->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'product_region','eq'=>'49')
))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `finset` instead of `eq` (multiple select values are stored in CSV format)

Comment: Thank you! 'finset' was the solution.

I have since looked up all the filter condition codes at http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

And, if like me you had not seen this before, finset means FIND_IN_SET()